# list flex : how to get the index of first visible element?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a simple list in Flex that is populated every N seconds by a dataprovider.  My goal is to avoid scrolling the list after the dataprovider has been changed.

So, before I populate the list, I save the `selectedIndex`, and once the `dataProvider` is filled, I call:

```
list.selectedIndex = index;
list.scrollToIndex(index);
```

Trouble is that this moves the selected item of the list to the top.

**The solution would be to get the index of the first element displayed in the list: but I have no idea on how to get that. Any clue?**

Perhaps something like: `list.getIndexFirstVisibleElement()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned if you're using Flex 4, but if you are you might want to look into `ensureIndexIsVisible`.

You can find an example here: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/05/12/scrolling-to-a-specific-index-in-a-spark-list-control-in-flex-4/.